# why any matrix of $SU(2)$ is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups, diagonalization

"Any matrix $A\in SU(2)$ can be written as $\begin{pmatrix}z & -\overline w \\ w & \overline z\end{pmatrix}$ for some $w,z\in\mathbb C$ with $|w|^2+|z|^2=1$.
Moreover, every matrix of this form is diagonalizable, that is, there exists $B\in SO(2)$ such that $BAB^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix."

I have read this statement but I do not understand why any matrix of $SU(2)$ is diagonalizable? and why the matrix that we will find will be in $SO(2)$ and not in $SU(2)$? can not it be with complex entries?

Comment: In general you need $B\in SU(2)$ not $SO(2)$. For example, let $$A=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1+i & -1+i \\ 1+i & 1-i\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then its eigenvectors are $((1+\sqrt{3})(1+i)/2,1)$ and $((1-\sqrt{3})(1+i)/2,1)$. So you cannot find a real matrix $B$ to diagonalize $A$.

Comment: Thank you @EclipseSun

Comment: @EclipseSun  I tried to calculate the eigenvalues for the matrix you mentioned but I did not get the values you get.

Comment: @hopefully I didn't calculate it myself. [Wolfram Alpha says so.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2Bi,-1%2Bi%7D,%7B1%2Bi,1-i%7D%7D%2F2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way over normal matrices is really the way to go here. However, you can also see the result by a simple investigation into the characteristic polynomial.

---

Take $$A=\begin{pmatrix}z &-\bar w\\w &\bar z\end{pmatrix},$$ then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is given by $$p_A(\lambda)=(z-\lambda)(\bar z-\lambda)+w\bar w=z\bar z-\bar z\lambda-z\lambda+\lambda^2+w\bar w$$
Now, for $z\in\mathbb C$, you have $z\bar z=|z|^2$, and thus as $|z|^2+|w|^2=1$:

$$p_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2-(z+\bar z)\lambda+1$$

Now, $\mathfrak R(z)=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}$ and thus

$$p_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2-2\mathfrak{R}(z)\lambda+1$$. You can now see that $p_A$ has two complex roots by looking at the discriminant of $p_A$:

$$(\frac{-2\mathfrak{R}(z)}{2})^2-1=(\mathfrak R(z))^2-1$$

and as $|z|^2<1$, you have $(\mathfrak R(z))^2<1$ and thus $(\mathfrak R(z))^2-1<0$. Thus, the matrix $A$ has two complex eigenvalues and thus can be diagonalized.

Comment: what is the theorem that relates diagonalization to eigenvalues?

Comment: Every eigenvalue has a corresponding eigenvector and for two pairwise distinct eigenvalues, the eigenvectors are linearly independent. Thus, if you have two eigenvectors for a linear map over $\mathbb C^2$, these form a basis of $\mathbb C^2$ and the matrix representation of the map w.r.t. this new basis, as you may easily verify, is a diagonal matrix where the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues.

Comment: so any matrix that have eigenvalues can be diagonalized?

Comment: @Smart No, but any two dimensional matrix with two distinct eigenvalues is diagonalizable.

Comment: can we find the eigenvalues exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Unitary matrices are normal, and therefore diagonalizable using a unitary $B$.

EDIT:
Look up [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix)

However, it is not true that $B$ is in $SO(2)$: that must be a misprint for $SU(2)$.  A rotation by an angle not a multiple of $\pi$ is a real member of $SU(2)$ with non-real eigenvalues, and therefore the $B$ can't be real.

For example, try $$A = \pmatrix{0 & -1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$$

where with $$B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \pmatrix{1 & i\cr i & 1\cr}$$ we have $$BAB^{-1} = \pmatrix{i & 0\cr 0 & -i}$$

Comment: what do you mean by a normal matrix?

Comment: @Smart They satisfy $U^\dagger U=UU^\dagger$.

Comment: And why this leads to that they are  diagonalizable using unitary $B$ could you give me a numeric (concrete)  example please?

Comment: In this statment "A rotation by an angle not a multiple of $π$ is a real member of $SU(2)$ with non-real eigenvalues" why the matrices A and B represent "A rotation by an angle not a multiple of $π$ i"

Comment: The matrix for a [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) by angle $\theta$ is $\pmatrix{\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\cr \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\cr}$.  This $A$ is the case $\theta = \pi/2$.