# why any matrix of $SU(2)$ is unitary diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups

Why any matrix of $SU(2)$ is unitary diagonalizable?

I know from here [why any matrix of $SU(2)$ is diagonalizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167375/why-any-matrix-of-su2-is-diagonalizable) that any matrix of $SU(2)$ is diagonalizable but why it is **unitary** diagonalizable?

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is unitary diagonalizable if and only if it is normal: [Normal Matrix, Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalMatrix.html). Every matrix in $SU(2)$ is normal, and the result follows.

Comment: and if we want to show that any matrix in $SU(2)$ is special unitary diagonalizable what shall we do ?